# Module not loading in Phalcon multi module

Tags: php, structure, phalcon, multi-module, hmvc

I have a problem for loading a module.php in multimodule.

[image: Here Directory structure for my app]

this the `Cores\Application`

```
<?php
namespace Cores;

use \Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault,
    \Phalcon\Loader,
     //\Phalcon\Registry,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\Router,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\Application as PhalconApplication,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\Events\Manager as EventsManager;

class Application extends PhalconApplication
{
    protected $_config;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $di = new FactoryDefault();

        $this->_config = Config::factory();
        parent::__construct($di);
    }

    private function __initModule()
    {
        $modulesDir = $this->_config->Config->application->modulesDir;
        $dir = [];

        /**
         * Faster way to load directory to find Modules
         */
        $objects = new \IteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($modulesDir));
        foreach($objects as $key => $ojb){
            if ($ojb->getFilename() != '.' AND $ojb->getFilename() != '..') {
                $dir[] = [
                    $ojb->getFilename() => [
                        'className' => 'Modules' . DS . $ojb->getFilename() . DS . 'Module',
                        'path'      => $ojb->getPath() .  '/' . $ojb->getFilename() . '/Module.php'
                    ]
                ];
            }
        }

        parent::registerModules($dir);
    }

    private function __initRoute()
    {
        $di = $this->getDI();
        $loader = new loader();
        $loader
            ->registerDirs([BASEPATH . 'App/Libraries/'])
            ->register();

        $di->set('router', function () {
            $router = new Router();

            $router->setDefaultModule('Administrator');

            $router->add('/:controller/:action', [
                'module'     => 'Modules\Administrator',
                'controller' => 1,
                'action'     => 2,
            ])->setName('Administrator');

            return $router;
        });
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->__initModule();
        $this->__initRoute();
        //echo '<pre>'.var_export($this->getModules(), true).'</pre>';
        try {
            echo $this->handle()->getContent();
        } catch (\Exception $err) {
            echo '<pre>'.var_export($err, true).'</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `Modules\Administrator` module.php

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Administrator

use \Phalcon\Loader,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\View,
    \Phalcon\DiInterface,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher,
    \Phalcon\Mvc\ModuleDefinitionInterface;

class Module implements ModuleDefinitionInterface
{
    /**
     * Register a specific autoloader for the module
     */
    public registerAutoloaders(DiInterface $di = null)
    {
        $loader = new Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces(
            [
                'Modules\\Administrator\\Controllers' => APP_PATH . '/Modules/Administrator/Controllers',
                'Moduels\\Administrator\\Models' => APP_PATH . '/Modules/Administrator/Models'
            ]
        );

        $loader->register();
    }

    /**
     * Register specific services for the module
     */
    public registerServices(DiInterface $di = null)
    {
        $di->set('dispatcher', function () {
            $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

            $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespaces('Modules\\Administrator\\Controllers');

            return $dispatcher;
        });

        $di->set('view', function () {
            $view = new View();

            $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . 'Administrator/Views/');

            return $view;
        });
    }
}
```

I think I was write "like" phalcon multi module in their site but the module.php is not loaded, why?

The err says `Module \'Administrator\' isn\'t registered in the application container`

Please explain this to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You don not need use \RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

```
$objects = new \IteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($modulesDir));
```

You need folders only from first level

```
$objects = new \IteratorIterator($modulesDir);
```

2.
Mistake with slash/backslash and main error is structure of array. Check structure in article https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/reference/applications.html#multi-module

```
$dir[] = [
    $ojb->getFilename() => [
         'className' => 'Modules' . DS . $ojb->getFilename() . DS . 'Module',
         'path'      => $ojb->getPath() .  '/' . $ojb->getFilename() . '/Module.php'
    ]
];
```

Must be

```
$dir[$ojb->getFilename()] = [
     'className' => 'Modules\\' . $ojb->getFilename() . '\\Module',
     'path'      => $ojb->getPath() .  DS . $ojb->getFilename() . DS . 'Module.php'
];
```

3.
In routes mistake in module name

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action', [
    'module'     => 'Modules\Administrator',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action'     => 2,
])->setName('Administrator');
```

Must be

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action', [
    'module'     => 'Administrator',
    'controller' => 1,
    'action'     => 2,
])->setName('Administrator');
```

Comment: Thanks brother. The error was was gone. But i still cant see my hello world string. The phtml was exist in views dir but it not shown. Why? I will mark it as answer later. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry brother. My false. I was got the response. The false is views directory in module. Thanks for ur answer. Its really help me. :D